# How to use the resulting array without further connection to the database? node js

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

There is a standard way to connect to oracle db.

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');


oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : "hr",
    password      : "mypw",
    connectString : "localhost/XEPDB1"
  },
  function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return;
    }
    connection.execute(
      `SELECT *
       FROM departments`,
      [],
        {
            outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT
        },  
      function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          doRelease(connection);
          return;
        }
        console.log(result.rows);
        doRelease(connection);
      });
  });

function doRelease(connection) {
  connection.close(
    function(err) {
      if (err)
        console.error(err.message);
    });
}
```

But how to make it so that the connection to the database is passed, then it receives an array that is stored in the database, and after that the connection was terminated. Then, in the future, to make it possible to use the resulting array to send requests for adding data, but for another database.

Comment: You may want to start with the async/await style of programming (see [example.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/example.js)) which can be easier to get right.  Then look at ways to insert data, such as [em_insert1.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/em_insert1.js).  Then work out what mapping you need to do in JS.

Comment: You might also be interested in seeing a high-level example, such as creating a REST API: https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/